# Linq update query using join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I just trying to Linq query update with join condition

```
 var GsOrderUpdate = (from x in ctxParser.Tbl_Order_Hierarchy
                 join y in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders
                 on x.RootOrder equals y.RelatedOrder
                 where y.ParentId == sParentId
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     RelatedOrderParentId = y.ID
                 });

foreach (var gs in GsOrderUpdate)
{
    gs.RelatedOrderParentId = gs.ID;
}

ctxParser.SaveChanges();
```

I am hetting this error:

> Property or indexer Anonymous type  RelatedOrderParentId cant be assigned to it is read only.

How can resolve this problem.

Comment: You cannot update anonymous types. You can only update entities.

Comment: LINQ can be used with many sources of data. Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Anonymous types cannot be assigned to -- it is read only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550797/c-sharp-anonymous-types-cannot-be-assigned-to-it-is-read-only)

Comment: what yo wanna do exactly, what is `RelatedOrderParentId ` which you are trying to update?.

Comment: Anonymous types don't have property set methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916695/property-or-indexer-anonymoustype1-firstname-cannot-be-assigned-to-it-is-r

Comment: Yes using Entity Framework doing code. and  public Nullable<int> RelatedOrderParentId { get; set; }  this is my property

Comment: Would you mind marking helpful answers to your questions as accepted? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You can't use anonymous type to update with EntityFramework.
If you want to update try so:

```
var GsOrderUpdate = (from x in ctxParser.Tbl_Order_Hierarchy
             join y in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders
             on x.RootOrder equals y.RelatedOrder
             where y.ParentId == sParentId
             select new
             {
                 Parent = x,
                 Child = y
             });

foreach (var gs in GsOrderUpdate)
{
    gs.Child.RelatedOrderParentId = gs.Parent.ID;
}

ctxParser.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework does not track changes in anonymous type objects. It only tracks changes in entities.

You can change your code to do something like this:

```
var GsOrderUpdate = (from x in ctxParser.Tbl_Order_Hierarchy
                 join y in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders
                 on x.RootOrder equals y.RelatedOrder
                 where y.ParentId == sParentId
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     Order = y
                 });

foreach (var gs in GsOrderUpdate)
{
    gs.Order.RelatedOrderParentId = gs.ID;
}

ctxParser.SaveChanges();
```

Now, you include the whole entity that you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity class instead of anonymous object:

```
var GsOrderUpdate = (from x in ctxParser.Tbl_Order_Hierarchy
                 join y in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders
                 on x.RootOrder equals y.RelatedOrder
                 where y.ParentId == sParentId
                 select new YourEntityName
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     RelatedOrderParentId = y.ID
                 });
```